# Testing without injection

Tags: testing, junit, mocking, code-injection

Most of what I've read about mocks, stubs (test doubles) involves some form of injection of the DOC either through the SUT method itself or constructor or setter methods.  And injecting that breaks boundaries like InjectMock are frowned upon as a regular test strategy.  But what if you are building a class that you do not want to expose those DOCs?  Is there a way to 'unit' test such a module?  Without AOP?  Is such a test not a real 'unit' test anymore?  Is the resistance I'm feeling really design smell and I should expose those DOCs somehow?

For example, lets say I have the following Class that I want to test (unit or otherwise):

```
public class RemoteRepository {
  Properties props = null;
  public RemoteRepository(Properties props) { this.props=props; }
  public Item export (String itemName) {
    JSch ssh = new JSch();
    ssh.setIdentity(props.get("keyfile"));
    ssh.connect();
    ssh.execute("export "+itemName+" "+props.get("exportFilename"));
    ...
}
```

Here is a unit I'd like to write a unit test for, but I want to stub or mock out the JSch component.  But the objects I create in the method to just do things that the method needs to accomplish are not exposed outside the method even.  So I cannot inject a stub to replace them.  I could change the export method signature to accept the stub, or add a constructor that does, but that changes my design just to suit a test.

Although the unit will connect to a real server to do the export in prod, when just testing the unit I either want to stub the DOC out completely, or simulate it with a real DOC that is simple and controlled.

This latter approach is like using an in memory db instead of a real one in that it acts and behaves like the eventual db that will be used, but can be confined to just what is needed for the test (eg. just the tables of interest, no heavy security, etc).  So I could setup some kind of test double sshd in my test so that when the build runs the test, it has something to test against.  This can be a lot of trouble to setup and maintain however and seems like overkill - sometimes trying to stub out a real DOC is harder than just using the real DOC somehow.

Am I stuck trying to setup a test framework that provides an sshd test double?  Am I looking at this the wrong way?  Do I just use AOP or mock library methods that break the class scope boundaries?

To restate the basic problem is that a lot of times I want to test a method that has complex DOCs (ie. those that interact with other systems: network, db, etc) and I don't want to change the design just to accommodate test double DOC injection.  How do you approach testing in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation, based on personal experience, is to write *integration* tests where DOCs (Depended On Components) are *not* mocked.

However, if for whatever reason the teams insists on having *unit* tests instead, you would have to either use a suitable mocking tool (AOP tools are able, but not a good fit here), or change the design of SUT and DOCs in order to use "weaker" mocking tools.